# How to set initial focus to a button in a viewController from a UITabBarController?

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, tvos, apple-tv

I have a basic application with a UITabBarController which contains 2 UIViewControllers.
The first ViewController has a UIButton in it.

I'm trying to get the tabBar menu hidden and the button focused when the app launches.
I set the tabBar as hidden, and it does not show on launch as expected. Unfortunately, the button doesn't have the focus.

From what I understand from Apple doc, the "focus chain" engine will set focus on the first visible and focusable item in the window hierarchy.

Can anyone help me on this ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution 1.
I think what you can do :

1.Subclass or Customize TabBarController and set
   set first launch = true in viewdidload of tabController

```
> override weak var preferredFocusedView: UIView? {   if
> (self.firstLaunch) {
>     self.firstLaunch = false;
>     return self.selectedViewController!.preferredFocusedView;   }   else {
>     let view  = super.preferredFocusedView
>     return view;   }
```

Hope it helps.It worked for me though

Your focus engine takes the rootView controller as TabBarController and then asks for preferred focus view which is returned as UITabBarItem we need to unfocus that subclassing the class and returning canBecomeFocus to NO.

if you want to change the focus of the element in the firtsViewController then you can overrirde func preferredFocusView and reutrn the view you want to be focussed else preferredFocusView

Solution 2. Just set the root View controller as the HomeViewController without the TabBarController and embed the TabBarController from the second page. This is because anyways you don't need to use TabBar on the first page why need to take care of its focus.

TabBar is set to hidden if you hide from the AppDelegate or the view which is loaded but it has the focus.

Comment: Solution #1 works great, thank you very much for your help.
I still need the tabBar, so solution #2 might not be the one for me.

I hide the tabBar from the Storyboard. 
So if I understand right:
Hidden elements are ignored when moving focus
Hidden elements are not ignored when determining the initial focus. Is that right ?

Comment: @Salah - No hidden element  may hide from the screen but they still has the focus.To prove this point when you already hidden the tabBar you were still seeing the focus was not coming on the button because the focus was still on the UITabBarButton. When the view loads in the window it asks the focus engine of the hierarchy in which focus should move. We cannot change the direction of focus but we can change the preferences of the focus. Let me know if you have any more questions?

Comment: I kind of understand but it still confuses me a little. Let's say you have a basic interface with 3 buttons in a row. If you set the button in the middle as hidden, it won't get the focus, so I thought I would have the same bahaviour in my case.